# PyGTK's GtkComboBox.clear_all() is very slow

Tags: python, pygtk

In my python script (using Glade for interface building) I have a few comboboxes that are regularly re-populated as options change.

This works fine when the list of options is short, like 10 or so. However it can also get longer, about 100 options is no exception. Now the problem is that clearing the list is very slow, it takes about 10 seconds during which the program hangs on that specific line.

Here a fragment of the code, where the combobox is cleared using `remove_all()` and then filled up again using `append_text()`. I've done some simple tests and found out that it's really the second line, with the `remove_all()` call, that is the culprit. The rest of the code runs fast.

```
    # Clear the combobox
    self.add_tour_selector.remove_all()

    # Populate the combobox.
    ids = [t['id'] for t in self.tours]
    for i in sorted(ids):
        self.add_tour_selector.append_text(i)

    self.add_tour_selector.set_active(0)
```

I'm looking for ways to drastically speed this up. Having to wait for my script to start responding again for that long is no fun. These comboboxes really have to be repopulated all the time as well, it's too hard to try to keep track of changing options and updating it.

The add_tour_selector is taken from the Glade file like this:

```
        self.add_tour_selector = self.builder.get_object('add_tour_selector')
```

`print`ing this gives `<ComboBoxText object at 0x7f3bdcb1b870 (GtkComboBoxText at 0x2ba22a0)>`

The ComboBoxText is populated like this:

```
    # Populate the combobox.
    ids = [t['id'] for t in self.tours]
    for i in sorted(ids):
        self.add_tour_selector.append_text(i)

    self.add_tour_selector.set_active(0)
```

One particularly slow one (with lots of entries - at least 100 - also a `ComboBoxText` object) is populated like this:

```
    # clear the combobox
    self.bookings_tour_selector.remove_all()

    # Populate the tour selector.
    self.bookings_tour_selector.append('0', 'all')

    for s in self.schedule:
        d = s['datetime'].strftime('%d/%m')
        self.bookings_tour_selector.append(str(s['number']), '%s %s'% (d, s['tourid']))
```

The `remove_all()` function is very slow, the rest of the code is fast.

Comment: You could try to use the ComboBox in combination with a TreeModel and modify that. The ComboBox can be created with `Gtk.ComboBox.new_from_model(model)`.

Comment: I don't know how I could implement this in my code, as the combobox is in the Glade layout already.

Comment: I am sorry. The ComboBox always uses a TreeModel but I am not quite sure what you are using because neither Gtk.ComboBox nor Gtk.ListStore have a `remove_all` method. Apart from that, the Gtk.ComboBox performs well with 100 entries.

Comment: Added some info to the question. Maybe the `remove_all` method is new in Gtk3, but it's really there.

Answer (score 0):

GtkComboBox.remove_all just calls (internally) ListStore.clear(), so there would be little benefit from replacing the ComboBoxText with ComboBox + Model.

However, 10 seconds to clear 100 elements from the list sounds incredibly slow. Debugging (and timing) these things are not easy to do. Widgets basically convert into two parts when used: The 'command' part, and the 'graphic' part, where the graphic part is executed asynchronously - it is converted into code that is executed when the main loop of the program is idle. So, it is possible that the remove_all is triggering a series of graphics commands from earlier in the program, which could be slow.

Also, much depends if you have defined the list to be sorted - sorting tends to be quite slow.

Finally, speed could also depend on if you have defined a renderering process which is complicated.

Here's simple example where remove_all is instantaneous (as far as I can see). I've set the number of elements to 1000 - it's actually the 'Fill' which is noticeably slow, probably because it updates the graphics in each loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_remove_all.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  


from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_size_request(200, -1)

        self.clear_btn = Gtk.Button("Clear")
        self.clear_btn.connect("clicked", self.clear_btn_clicked)
        self.add_btn = Gtk.Button("Add 100")
        self.add_btn.connect("clicked", self.add_btn_clicked)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("0 elements")
        self.combo = Gtk.ComboBoxText()
        self.add_btn_clicked(self)

        self.vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.clear_btn, False, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.add_btn, False, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.label, False, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.combo, False, True, 0)

        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def clear_btn_clicked(self, btn):
        self.combo.remove_all()

    def add_btn_clicked(self, btn):
        for n in range(100):
            self.combo.append_text("String %d" % n)

        self.combo.set_active(1)
        model = self.combo.get_model()
        self.label.set_text("%d elements" % model.iter_n_children(None))

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Click Add 100 several times, then Clear - it's very fast. In fact, I tried till several 1000s. Only at 1000s, things get slow.

Comment: Nothing special really that I added to the list. Elements are added in order (sorted before the append_text is called), and no graphical things added by me. The main difference with your example is that I'm using a Glade interface design.

Comment: Glade shouldn't matter. Glade has little or no impact on the ComboBoxText. try adding, say, 3000 items, and then try selecting or scrolling. You'll see the slowness I think you refer to. Clear continues to work very fast though. Did you notice any slowness with a couple of 100 items added in my program?